# Multi-dimensional array sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a multi-dimensional array in javascript defined as :-

```
myArray[0][0] = Some IMage;
myArray[0][1] = Some price;
myArray[0][2] = Some name;
myArray[0][3] = Some values;
myArray[0][4] = Some otherValues;
myArray[1][0] = Some IMage;
myArray[1][1] = Some price;
myArray[1][2] = Some name;
myArray[1][3] = Some values;
myArray[1][4] = Some otherValues;
```

Now my job is to sort them according to the price . How can this be done ?

Comment: I would say, don't use a multi-dimensional array like that. Have an array of objects which store the info and then sort the objects.

Comment: How to use object for storing the values ? Should I save the values as myArray[0]["image"] = some Image; ..etc ?

Comment: Should be something like `var arr = []; arr.push({ img: '', price: 99, name: 'Name', values: 123, otherValues: 987 });` Let's say you pushed multiple *objects* into this array. Then you can access the first object's price by `arr[0].price` and the second by `arr[1].price`.

Comment: Ok Thanks ! I will implement this :D

Comment: You have two arrays with price values in them `myArray[0]` and `myArray[1]`.  Do you want each array sorted separately?  Do you want all price values sorted together and then replaced with the first 5 values in one array and the last 5 values in the second array?  How do you want it sorted?  We can't answer the question without knowing this.

Comment: I wish all the values sorted according to their corresponding price.

Comment: Although it would be wiser to implement it using objects (ie. for readability), nothing prohibits you to implement it using array inside array. See: http://jsfiddle.net/vZAYY/14/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per my comment above, you should probably use objects instead of multi-dimensional arrays. Here's an example (imagine your additional attributes like `name` and `IMage` included, which I didn't include for the sake of less typing)

```
var arr = [
    { price: 12, something: 'a b c' },
    { price: 8, something: 'a b c' },
    { price: 45, something: 'a b c' },
    { price: 10, something: 'a b c' }
];

arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a.price - b.price; });

/*
    arr is now:

    [ 
        { price: 8, something: 'a b c' },
        { price: 10, something: 'a b c' },
        { price: 12, something: 'a b c' },
        { price: 45, something: 'a b c' } 
    ]
*/
```

Comment: Just a small doubt. How will I create the object above given I have the values in 5 different arrays ?

Comment: what do you mean five diff arrays? What does each array store?

Comment: First one has the price, second one has the name n so n so . I just wish to say given the values How can I make such object ? In other words, How to push tha values into object

Comment: so if you have `var names = ['Tim', 'Prashant']` and `var prices = [12, 25]` you can do `var arr = []; for(var i = 0, l = names.length; i < l; i++) { arr.push({ name: names[i], price: prices[i] }); }` and then sort. Does that work with what you mean?

Comment: That script requires that the separate arrays are the same length. It loops based on the `names` array. Which is not bullet-proof. And won't be as long as you have to work with these disconnected arrays.

Comment: arr.sort() can use a comparison function that is a dictionary object.  for example the comparison function can be compare(a, b) {return a.price > b.price;);} arr.sort(compare(a, b));   I'm not sure which is faster using a.price - b.price or a.price > b.price ... that maybe a topic for analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer without judgement of the data structure in case someone searches the question. "Improper" structure like this is sometimes needed (eg: as input for dataTables).

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a[1] - b[1]; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have a sort function that accepts another function as  comparator. You can sort your data like this:

```
var comparator= function(a,b){
   var price1 = a[1], price2=b[1]; // use parseInt() if your "price" are quoted 
   if( price1 < price2) return -1;
   else return 1;
   return 0;
};
myArray.sort(comparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

Borrowed from Marshall.

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push({
    image: 'some image',
    price: 1.5,
    name: 'name',
    values: 'values',
    otherValues: 'otherValues'
});

myArray.push({
    image: 'some image2',
    price: 0.5,
    name: 'name2',
    values: 'values2',
    otherValues: 'otherValues2'
});

myArray.push({
    image: 'some image3',
    price: 2.5,
    name: 'name3',
    values: 'values3',
    otherValues: 'otherValues3'
});

myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.price - b.price;
});

alert(myArray[0].price);
alert(myArray[1].price);
alert(myArray[2].price);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript Multi-Criteria / Multi-Parameter Sort**

If you want to sort an array by a single value, or by multiple-values you can define the following function:

```
function sortByCriteria(data, criteria) {
    return data.sort(function (a, b) {

        var i, iLen, aChain, bChain;

        i = 0;
        iLen = criteria.length;
        for (i; i < iLen; i++) {        
            aChain += a[criteria[i]];
            bChain += b[criteria[i]];
        }

        return aChain.localeCompare(bChain);
    });
}
```

Then invoke like this:

```
var data = [
    { price: 12, something: 'a b c' },
    { price: 8, something: 'a b c' },
    { price: 45, something: 'a b c' },
    { price: 10, something: 'a b c' }
];
var criteria = ["price", "something"];

sortByCriteria(data, criteria);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oahxg4u3/6/